# "прообраз" и "праобраз"

Tags: орфография, приставка

Почему слово "прообраз" пишется с приставкой про-? Ведь лексическое значение этого слова - это то, что служит, послужило образцом, образом для чего-либо, т.е. то, что было изначально, **первоначальное**. Такое значение в русском языке имеет приставка пра-, так почему слово "прообраз" пишется с про-? Объясните, пожалуйста, год этим вопросом уже мучаюсь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему, в этом слове значение приставки "про-" = "вперёд, сквозь время".

Из "Словаря церковно-славянского и русского языка" середины 19-го века:

***ПРООБРАЗ** -- то же, что **проображ**ение, прознаменование (предзнаменование).*

Интересно, что у Ушакова значение *прототип* у слова *прообраз* ещё не фиксировалось. См. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/984802 :

> **ПРОО́БРАЗ**... Образ, образец будущего. *«В героях воздуха, моря и
> Арктики, в героях борьбы со стихиями,
> ряды которых растут на наших глазах,
> мы видим прообраз героев борьбы против
> любого врага СССР.»* Молотов. *СССР -
> прообраз грядущего человеческого
> общества во всем мире.*
>
> *Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.*

Answer (score 5):

ПРА...
Первая часть сложных слов.

1. Вносит зн.: первоначальный; исконный, древний. Праистория, прапамять, прародина, праславянский, праязык.
2. Обозначает прямую степень родства по восходящей и нисходящей линии (начиная с деда, бабки или внука, внучки). Прабабка, правнук, прадед, прапрадедушка, праправнучка.
3. Обозначает предков вообще. Праматерь, праотцы, прапредки, прародители, прародичи, прапращур.

ПРООБРАЗ, -а; м.

1. То, что служит, послужило образом для чего-л., образ будущего. П. нового общества. П. совершенного города.
2. Лицо, послужившее основой для создания литературного персонажа; прототип. Кто послужил прообразом героини?

---

Почувствуйте разницу.